# Material Angular styling doesn't work for <md-card> on ui-views

Tags: css, angularjs, partials, angularjs-material

I want to get this effect on the ui-views

```
<md-card id="sidebar" flex="20" class="sche-card" layout-padding="true">
<div ui-view="card" autoscroll="false"></div>
</md-card>
```

The problem, with this is I get an empty card when the view is not enabled.
I have tried this inside the partial. It breaks the styling and the card doesn't show properly.

**partial.html**

```
<md-card id="sidebar" flex="20" class="sche-card" layout-padding="true">
<p>Card Contents</p>
</md-card>
```

What is correct way to use **md-card** in partials?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping in

```
<div layout="row" layout-wrap>
   <!-- cards here -->
</div>
```

Or put those attributes on `<ui-view>` if always the same